# Kivy No User Input Display

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm struggling with what should be a simple Python/Kivy program. Unlike all the examples I've been trying to follow, my program uses absolutely zero user input. It simply pulls data from a 3rd party website, runs a few calculations, and then displays the results. The results are updated every 30 minutes.

I have yet to figure out how to correctly pass the data from Python to Kivy. What am I failing to grasp?

I've greatly simplified the program to the following:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class GetData():
    red_flag = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    green_flag = [0, 1, 0, 1]

    def data_grab(self):
        '''
        In the real program, the raw data is pulled from 3rd party website
        Then calculations are performed on the raw data and then formatted
        I realize in this sample program that the data never changes
        '''
        se_days = ['4/3', '4/4']
        so_last_update = '4/5 1:31 PM'
        itd_status = [self.green_flag, self.red_flag]
        return se_days, so_last_update, itd_status

class TheBox(FloatLayout):
    day3 = ObjectProperty(None)
    day2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    lastupdate = ObjectProperty(None)
    inv1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    inv2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update_data(self, *args):
        d = GetData()
        data_list = d.data_grab()
        se_days = data_list[0]
        so_last_update = data_list[1]
        itd_status = data_list[2]

        self.day3.text = se_days[0]
        self.day2.text = se_days[1]
        self.lastupdate.text = 'Last Updated at: ' + so_last_update
        self.inv1.background_color = itd_status[0]
        self.inv2.background_color = itd_status[1]

class DisplayTestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        time_interval = 30   # minutes
        x = TheBox()
        x.update_data()
        Clock.schedule_interval(x.update_data, time_interval*60)
        return TheBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DisplayTestApp().run()
```

With the Kivy file:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<DayLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: .4, .1
    font_size: '24sp'
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    halign: 'right'

<InvLabel@Button>:
    size_hint: .2, .15
    font_size: '48sp'
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    halign: 'center'

<TheBox>:
    day3: day3
    day2: day2
    lastupdate: lastupdate
    inv1: inv1
    inv2: inv2
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: .35, .5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .4, 'center_y': .5}
            DayLabel:
                id: day3
                pos_hint: {'right': .08, 'center_y': .9}
                text: ''
            DayLabel:
                id: day2
                pos_hint: {'right': .08, 'center_y': .7}
                text: ''
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: .2, .6
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .55}
            InvLabel:
                id: inv2
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .5, .5, .5, 1
                text: '2'
            InvLabel:
                id: inv1
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .2}
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: .5, .5, .5, 1
                text: '1'
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: .8, .15
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .15}
            Label:
                id: lastupdate
                size_hint: .9, .2
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
                font_size: '18sp'
                color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                halign: 'center'
                text: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that you are updating an instance of `TheBox` that is not in your GUI. the

```
    return TheBox()
```

in your `build()` method is creating a new instance of `TheBox` and returning that as the root of your GUI.

The lines:

```
    x = TheBox()
    x.update_data()
    Clock.schedule_interval(x.update_data, time_interval*60)
```

are also creating an instance of `TheBox`, and calling its `update_data()` method. But that instance does not appear in your GUI.

The simple fix is to replace:

```
return TheBox()
```

with:

```
return x
```

Comment: That's it! I was looking at everything, but never considered that. Thanks!